# How to copy a file with file owner and ACLs infos on window by python?

Tags: python, file, copy

The **shutil** module contains several methods to copy the files but as the doc warned they don't copy all the metadata such as file owners and ACLs are not included on window.

The command line could be called to bypass this, such as:

```
subprocessl.call('copy src dst')
```

Is there more pythonic way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Taken from http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/copy-a-file.html
This would copy ACL's by calling the win32 library essentially doing a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in windows.

```
import os
import win32file
import tempfile

filename1 = tempfile.mktemp (".txt")
open (filename1, "w").close ()
filename2 = filename1 + ".copy"
print filename1, "=>", filename2

#
# Do a straight copy first, then try to copy without
# failing on collision, then try to copy and fail on
# collision. The first two should succeed; the third
# should fail.
#
win32file.CopyFile (filename1, filename2, 1)
win32file.CopyFile (filename1, filename2, 0)
win32file.CopyFile (filename1, filename2, 1)

if os.path.isfile (filename2): print "Success"

dirname1 = tempfile.mktemp (".dir")
os.mkdir (dirname1)
dirname2 = dirname1 + ".copy"
print dirname1, "=>", dirname2

#
# The CopyFile functionality doesn't seem to cope
# with directories.
#
win32file.CopyFile (dirname1, dirname2, 1)

if os.path.isdir (dirname2): print "Success"
```

Comment: Thank you! Coincidentally, I'm reading this guy's another article about add file security to a file.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes this lad has done quite a few amazing things within the Python community. I particularly like the `WMI` documentation he has when working with Windows: http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/tutorial.html

Comment: OK, I will read it. The article I have mentioned is http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/add-security-to-a-file.html. Thank you for your sharing.